# Assets Content/Fields not available until entry is saved?

Tags: assets, field, entry, modal

I've got Asset location setup with a Photo Caption field. And a Photo Gallery field which references said Asset.

When creating a new entry, I'm uploading images to the Photo Gallery field. When the images are uploaded, double-clicking brings up the modal but the Photo Caption field is **not** available. Only after saving the entry and then re-opening it to edit is the Photo Caption field available in the Assets modal.

Is the normal behavior? Did I miss something?

It would be ideal for my clients to be able to edit the photo meta information while they're creating a new entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue with Assets fields if you have a dynamic Subfolder path set on in the field’s settings. It’s been fixed for 2.3 though ;)

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for the reply, Brandon. Thought I was going crazy. :-D I'm really enjoying learning Craft. You guys are doing great work. Keep it up!